# Write to a list without contribute rights

Tags: list, web-part, permissions

Is there an out of box visual webpart which lets a user add items to a list with only read rights?

I can think of a WF, which gives the user the needed rights and takes it away afterwards. Is there an other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get this type of requirement, you normally start with trying to understand what the real business case is. I mean, the security model in SharePoint is there for just that, security. When you get requirements trying to bypass it, you should be careful and really make sure to understand the real need.

With that said, there are cases when you need to do it (like allowing anonymous users to sign up for an event). In those cases we use some kind of elevation of permissions.

This can be done with a workflow impersonation step as you mention. It can also be done in C# by using `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` (code will run as the application pool account) or with the overload of `new SPSite(string, SPUserToken)` that takes a user token as input parameter.